# Android Textview onTouchEvent

Tags: java, android, textview, touch-event

I'm trying to have a TextView follow my finger on touch. I have no idea on how to get this to work because none of the layouts use a coordinates system. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an absolute layout, but it's depricated. Not sure if you can do this with any "pretty" and "slick" look to it, but perhaps you can achieve something with relative layout.

[Android: Placing a view in an arbitrary location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093296/android-placing-a-view-in-an-arbitrary-location)

Comment: Thanks, the example you provided doesnt seem to work and I am trying to stay away from Absolute Layout since it is deprecated and who knows when it will be removed.